# Exit for loop array length

Tags: java, for-loop

For some reason I cannot break out of the for statement in the below code. I have tried using arr.length and arr.length - 1.

```
    static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    int pos = 0, neg = 0;
    int zero = 0;
    double posDec = 0, negDec = 0, zeroDec = 0;
    int length =  arr.length;



    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

        if(arr[i] < 0)
            neg+=1;
        else if(arr[i] > 0)
            pos+=1;
        else
            zero+=1;



    }  

    posDec = pos/arr.length;
    negDec = neg/arr.length;
    zeroDec = zero / arr.length;

    System.out.println(posDec + "/n" + negDec + "/n" + zeroDec);


}
```

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot break out"? I'm pretty sure that's a finite loop.

Comment: I cannot recreate the supposed issue you are talking about so I am voting to close. It breaks out of the loop just fine for me. There might be some other issue in your program separate from this method.

Comment: There are two definite bugs in your program, both of which Elliott has correctly identified.  Neither of them has anything to do with breaking out of the loop.  So can you please clarify what is going wrong for you?  Your description isn't particularly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs I see, one you are promoting the integer division to a double. Two, you are using `/n` instead of `\n`. Additionally, I would prefer a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and you can use `++` instead of `+= 1`. Like,

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
    int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;

    for (int val : arr) {
        if (val < 0)
            neg++;
        else if (val > 0)
            pos++;
        else
            zero++;
    }

    double posDec = pos / (double) arr.length;
    double negDec = neg / (double) arr.length;
    double zeroDec = zero / (double) arr.length;
    System.out.println(posDec + "\n" + negDec + "\n" + zeroDec);
}
```

Comment: You can add one more , if `arr.length` is zero will get an `ArithmeticException`